# Flip of cards 180deg (HTML,CSS,JS)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, frontend

I have a problem that my cards rotate, but each card moves to ~5px (X-axis). How can I rotate them without this movement? (Just like rotate it around itself). I've read many specs and watched many videos. Nothing could help me.
Besides, whenever I click on some cards to return them in a previous state, some of them do it for a second or even a third time.

```js
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".memory-card")

function flip() {
  this.classList.toggle("flip")
}

cards.forEach((c) => c.addEventListener("click", flip))
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  background: linear-gradient(50deg, rgb(198, 193, 188), rgb(153, 145, 137), rgb(109, 101, 94));
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  position: fixed;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 15vmin/ 20vmin 20vmin 20vmin 20vmin;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 8vmin;
  margin-left: -2vmin;
  perspective: 1000px;
  grid-gap: 8vmin 4vmin;
}


/*flip moment*/

.memory-card {
  width: calc(25%-10px);
  height: calc(14vmin - 2px);
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(1);
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  margin: 2vw;
  transition: .5s;
  border-radius: 23%;
  box-shadow: 1vmin 1vmin 1vmin 2px silver;
  transition: transform .5s;
}

.memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.memory-card:active {
  transform: scale(0.94);
  transition: .05s;
}

.front {
  position: absolute;
  width: 19vmin;
  height: 19vmin;
  border-radius: 15px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.end {
  position: absolute;
  width: 19vmin;
  height: 19vmin;
  border-radius: 15px;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset=U TF-8>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width = device-width, initial-scale = 1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  <title> Memory Game </title>
</head>

<body>
  <section class="wrapper">
    <div class="memory-card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1484589065579-248aad0d8b13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=918&q=80" alt="space" class="front">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/A_black_image.jpg/1600px-A_black_image.jpg?20201103073518" alt="a black card" class="end">
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1516339901601-2e1b62dc0c45?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=671&q=80" alt="space" class="front">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/A_black_image.jpg/1600px-A_black_image.jpg?20201103073518" alt="a black card" class="end">
    </div>

    <div class="memory-card">
      <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444703686981-a3abbc4d4fe3?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1740&q=80" alt="space" class="front">
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/49/A_black_image.jpg/1600px-A_black_image.jpg?20201103073518" alt="a black card" class="end">
    </div>


  </section>
  <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `transform-origin` when your cards flip. This property allows you to change the position of transformed elements. Learn more at [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform-origin.asp):

```
 .memory-card.flip {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  transform-origin: 85% 50%;
}
```

Comment: It is more helpful to future readers in particular if you could explain why this works - especially how the 85% was arrived at and how this makes things responsive.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that I don't think it does work on different viewport sizes - I could only get it working on my laptop max viewport width.

Comment: yeah, I've done the same, but with 10vmin 10vmin. Anyways, thanks